# Was first stanza 'नारायणं नमस्कृत्य' of Mahabharata a later interpolation?

Tags: mahabharata, interpolation

> It has been mentioned earlier that the Mahabharata was in the custody of the Brahmins of the Bhrgu race. The epic got its vast size even before the rise and development of the Gupta reign. The tendency to enlarge the Mahabharata text was still continued by these Brahmins.
> In their own interest, these Brahmins wrote the Puranas and rearranged them.
> It is a notable fact that Lord Krishna had not a prominent role to play even in the first connected epic narrative.
> **The studies of Sri V.S. Sukthankar reveal the fact that the very first stanza 'नारायणं नमस्कृत्य" etc. is a later interpolation to the Mahabharata**, a pure Vaishnava composition.

The above passage was quoted from sodhganga articles already by an user [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42374).

My question is what are those studies and what are the evidence available to support these claims.

Comment: Good question.  Even I am curious to know

Comment: @Srimannarayana K V. Yeah, an open minded approach to know the truth. If those studies and evidences worth their salt, these claims can be accepted. Btw, you didn't answered me, Are you sure Ramanuja quoted 'tad visnoh' sloka or else it is you showing him in bad light?

Comment: Related: [Is the “narayanam namaskrtya” benedictory initial stanza present in the critical editions of the Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32405/is-the-narayanam-namaskrtya-benedictory-initial-stanza-present-in-the-critical)

Comment: Indeed, he seems to agree that the verse is present in some manuscripts of mahabharata. No where in that pdf he mentioned that verse is an interpolation, BORI too contains that verse. //This verse is present mainly in the Northern manuscripts as per Vishnu Sukthankar. Very few Southern manuscripts contain this verse.//  could you please isolate this for me in the pdf? @idol worshipper. Even that does not sounds like a great excuse to label it as an interpolation. I am looking for reason to consider it as an interpolation.

Comment: @YDS I am aware of that, but my question is specific to sukthankar's evidence.

Comment: @idol worshipper. Thank you, sukthankar despite having that view,seems he did not opined it to be interpolation as there is no statement explicitly made by him in the pdf. Is this the only study of sukthankar? Or is it the author of quoted article assuming things?

Comment: Unbelievable! 4 close-votes already...let me get my answer in before it gets closed.

Comment: Too late, it's already closed...interestingly, one of the users who wanted to know the answer has closed it as well. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @sv. Btw how does that Answer answers my question? My question is specific to Sukthankars rejection of that verse and why he did so? Any knowledgable person please enlighten me

Comment: @idol worshipper. I thought Sukthankar made another critical edition . I got my answer. So it is that sodhganga article author's own assumption.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42879/2995). I was going to post the second half here but this question was closed before I could.